# Browsers only work in safe mode Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, networking, browser

I'm running Windows 10 Home edition and I keep it up to date along with most of the other software on my PC.
About 5 days ago Chrome suddenly started to give ERR_CONNECTION_Aborted for every page I tried to access. So I switched to MS Edge to hunt for a solution. This continued to work for about another 24 hours when It too started giving similar errors on every page. Firefox also refused to access any pages with PR_CONNECT_RESET_ERROR.
Fortunately I have a bootable USB stick with a cut down version of Windows (Hiren) and this has enabled me to try to track down the problem along with my Android smartphone.
The USB Windows 10 browsers work
ping google.com and 8.8.8.8 work with no problem
FTP works
WhatsApp works
Thunderbird email client works
So the hardware and internet connection is OK, the problem lies inside Windows.

Searching out articles on the problem has thrown up a number of suggested solutions, many of them involving the command line. NONE of them has made any difference:-
ipconfig /release
ipconfig /renew
ipconfig /flushdns
netsh int ip reset
net winsoc reset
nbtstat -R
nbstat -RR

Settings > Network > Network reset
Chrome > Settings > Reset
Trying to reinstall Chrome fails as the  installer can't get access to the server to download the files. But I doubt this matters as the problem is common to 3 different browsers.

The only thing that has worked is starting Windows in safe mode with networking, which is allowing me to ask this question (all 3 browsers are working). Can anyone suggest what is going wrong? Should I disable Kaspersky anti virus? I'm guessing that something has deranged the Port 80 settings in full Windows mode, but what?
This is obviously still WIP and I still have a few things to try, but I really really don't want to reinstall Windows from scratch!

**Some time later.**

I've tried both the suggestions in the answer, but, as John feared, neither work. Interestingly I downloaded the reinstall tool and a copy of the ISO file. Mounting the ISO allowed me to try a repair install, which, unless I've missed something, is now called "reinstall keeping your apps and settings" but to no avail. I guess the problem may be in the registry settings as, surely, reinstalling Windows would have replaced any code/drivers pertaining to Port 80 but kept the registry.

I also tried an identical repair install using the download tool which appears to work up to the last step when it says it's failed and sits there on a 30 second repeating cycle trying to access something until you close the error window.

I know I'm dragging my heels, but the last thing I want to do is a complete reinstall of everything unless I absolutely have to. Particularly as I have a 95% functional system that just needs booting between ordinary (sound + 2 screens + no web pages) and safe mode (no sound, 1 screen but working browsers). I'm still living in hope that I'll find a fix.

**Final attempt.**

There is no hardware or network problem as other internet using programs are fine.
A repair install of Windows presumably reinstalls all the built in code and drivers, so it's not there either.
The only thing left is the stuff I've kept between installs, the apps and settings. But it's all browsers that experience the problem so it must be down to common settings = the registry. Can I restore the registry from one of a multitude of backups created over the years? It would have to be a recent backup and hopefully a full one, but sadly none such exists, only a month old partial from CCleaner, and sadly it doesn't work either.
However, one, and only one web site has started to work - YouTube! Why? I don't know, there is still no luck with other sites such as Netflix or Amazon Prime. But there is some life in Family Tree Maker which has a built in browser, it can now access maps worldwide and possibly other genealogical sites.

Comment: `Should I disable Kaspersky anti virus` try that - or check its firewall settings (assuming it has any)

Comment: Was Kasperski for me too. Netstat commands did nothing, while ping google.com worked. Planning to switch to a different antivirus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was Kaspersky after all!!
A couple of days ago, to add to my woes, the power supply in my PC failed and I didn't have a spare, so I was obliged to take it to a local repairer in Oxford. They also agreed to have a look at this problem. They were most surprised when, on disabling Kaspersky, it all started working again. They couldn't explain it even after looking at all the settings, particularly why YouTube was the only site I could find that was unaffected.
So Jaromanda X was right and John and I guessed wrong.
Kaspersky is now completely uninstalled as we couldn't find a workable solution with it still present. I'm looking for new antivirus software.
At least I didn't have to do a complete format and reinstall of Windows and all my apps.

Comment: Same for me. Kasperski broke internet.

Answer (score 1):

Given your description,  Kasperky is not likely the culprit unless it is broken as well.

**(1) Start with DISM / SFC.**

> (1) Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.
>
> (2) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /StartComponentCleanup
>
> (3) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /Restorehealth
>
> (4) SFC /SCANNOW
>
> (5) Restart when all the above is complete and test.

I do not hold out a lot of hope for this initial repair.

**(2) If DISM / SFC does not work, try a Windows 10 Repair Install.**

> Go to the Windows Media Creation Link
>
> https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10
>
> Windows 10 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade
> Button) and select Run. This will launch the Repair.  Proceed normally
> answering the prompts. The default Keep prompt is to Keep Everything

Now if all the above fails, either the Windows User Profile is damaged or there is more serious OS damage.

**(3) In either case above, back everything up and install Windows fresh**

Comment: Sadly I've tried (1), but, as you expected it didn't work.

Comment: You should then try the Repair Install and see if that helps and if not, then you may need to reinstall Windows.

Comment: my post should have been :- It's taken me some time to get here, amongst other things I've been amassing all the assets I'll need to recreate most of my desktop if I have to format the installation disk (C:). Sadly I've tried (1), but, as you expected it didn't work. (2) has it's own problems. I can only download the install tool in safe mode but it says it cannot install stuff in this mode, so I used it to create an iso image, mounted it and did a reinstall keeping apps and settings. But again to no effect. But it looks as if I'm going to have to do a clean reinstall after all.

Comment: But thanks John for pushing me reluctantly in the right direction!

Comment: I've added some further details of unsuccessful fixes, but I don't know if any give you a clue as to what's gone wrong.

Comment: I reviewed your added input and do not have further ideas at this point.  You may need to try the fresh install at this point.

Comment: The troublemaker is Kasperski. The problem dissapears once you turbn off Kasperski.